# formatting issue in validation control

Tags: asp.net

I i'm using more than 1 validation for a text box in that case if 1st validation is not passed then the second validation is showing after some blank space that is for 1st validator.In my project for email textbox i'm using two validation requiredfield and regular expression but my regular expression validator not showing on right place.I tried css i.e left-margin but that not works for me.
[image: my issue is shown in pic]
my code is
    
        
            
                First Name
            
            
                
                
            
        
        
            
                Last Name
            
            
                
                
            
        
        
            
                Email Id

```
        &nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            User Id
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox7" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" Height="22px" Width="189px"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4"  runat="server" 
                ControlToValidate="TextBox7" 
                ErrorMessage="It is a mandatory field Can't be left blank" ForeColor="#FF3300"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

        </td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Password
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" TextMode="Password" Height="22px" Width="189px"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5"  runat="server" 
                ForeColor="#FF3300" ControlToValidate="TextBox4" ErrorMessage="It is a mandatory field Can't be left blank"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Full Address
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" Height="64px" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="189px"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator  ID="RequiredFieldValidator6" runat="server" 
                ForeColor="#FF3300" ControlToValidate="TextBox5" ErrorMessage="It is a mandatory field Can't be left blank"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Mobile No.
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator7" runat="server" 
                ForeColor="#FF3300" ControlToValidate="TextBox4" ErrorMessage="It is a mandatory field Can't be left blank"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator1" runat="server" 
               ForeColor="#FF3300" ControlToValidate="TextBox6" ErrorMessage="Not in the correct format" 
                MaximumValue="9999999999" MinimumValue="1000000000"></asp:RangeValidator>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" 
        ImageUrl="~/img/str/buttons/submit_blue.png" onclick="ImageButton1_Click" />
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try setting your validator's **Display** property to *Dynamic*. The default value for that property is *Static*, which means your validator's html is rendered with the *visibility:hidden* css rule, while with Dynamic it gets a *display:none* css rule instead. The *visibility:hidden* css rule will leave empty whitespace in place of an element, *display:none* won't.

Answer (score -1):

you should divide the sections of data and validators. a Table will be fine or div sections

[image]

As you can see  - if you put a table with td's so each side will have its own td. so when the break line occurs , the new line will be beneath the first one.
Also you will have to make some `float:left` inside you html for the red lines.

In a same manner , you can use div with fixed width.

Comment: Please explain with some example

Comment: I did that but my regular expression error comes after some blank space

Comment: the comment box only allow 600 character i don't where to paste my code